# PHPStorm: Error Loading Default Project

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

The last thing I did in PHPStorm was install a plugin, then I believe it crashed (or I shut it down, I forget). After restarting, any time I open a project I get the following error:

```
Error Loading Default Project

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: 
com/intellij/openapi/compiler/CompilerManager
[Plugin: com.siberika.idea.pascal]
```

Anyone know how to get around this so I can use my IDE? Thanks!

Comment: try disabling this plugin in Settings/Plugins - does it help?

Comment: Actually I can't even load the application. When I try to create a new project I get the same error.

Comment: So .. have you uninstalled the plugin or not?

Comment: Nope. I'm not able to get into the IDE to uninstall it. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: Then delete it manually while IDE is closed: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: There are no plugins in that folder specified, just some jar files. The names aren't clear enough to know what to remove.

Comment: Solved. I just Leroy'd it and completely uninstalled & reinstalled as per: http://7php.com/uninstall-phpstorm-macosx/

Comment: Well at least you had chicken. ;)

Comment: For the future: *"There are no plugins in that folder specified, just some jar files"* -- those ARE the plugins (.jar is a normal .zip file); *"The names aren't clear enough to know what to remove"* -- then remove all of them -- you can reinstall those other custom plugins again.

Comment: Nice, thanks LazyOne! Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the plugin from the plugins directory did not work for me. I was able to fix this error by doing the following.

1. Open Intellij IDE from **idea.exe** or **idea64.exe**
2. And then from the Splash Screen there should be an option to access
   plugins
3. From the plugins screen you can now uninstall the plugin causing the
   error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To delete a broken or unsupported plugin in PHPStorm (or any InteliJ based IDE), you can do it manually.

1. Go to the plugins folder and delete the folder or `jar` file that corresponds with the  plugin causing the exception.
2. Restart PHPStorm

### Plugins folders by OS

- Linux and other Unix systems: `~/.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`
- Windows Vista, 7, 8: `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>\config\plugins`
- Windows XP: `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Documents and Settings\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>\config\plugins`
- Mac OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

e.g.: Plugins folders for PHPStorm 9.0 in Mac OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/WebIde90`

More information about InteliJ directories [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827437-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).